# Query function only showing data if 2 valid items

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a Query command that will pull my active options out of a ledger/entries list and place them in a summary list. If I have 2 open non expired options it works but if I have only 1 it does not show anything. Any suggestions?

Here is my Query command.

=query(Entries,"select C, D, E, H, I, L where L>-1 order by L asc limit 9")

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gBqf1xWfg-8VIDMbcsE8sIT_ep9AhraJsHfUTtZkUms/edit?usp=sharing

If I label the last option as open both show up but if I leave it off then the 1 valid entry does not show up? Any suggestions

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Your sheet2 showing result? What problem are you facing?

Comment: I have changed the sheet to public. I am checking by deleting the value in G10 on sheet 1 or having it Open value. If I only have 1 valid active option and it says in W22 where I have the query that query completed with empty output. If I change the G10  to open so I have 2 active options it then populates and shows 2 options. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Entries, 
 "select C, D, E, H, I, L 
  where L>-1 
  order by L asc 
  limit 9", )
```

---

### update:

```
=SORTN(FILTER({'Wheel Strategy Template'!C6:E, 'Wheel Strategy Template'!H6:I, 'Wheel Strategy Template'!L6:L}, 
 VALUE('Wheel Strategy Template'!L6:L)>-1), 9, 1, 6, 1)
```

or:

```
=SORTN(FILTER({'Wheel Strategy Template'!C6:E, 'Wheel Strategy Template'!H6:I, 'Wheel Strategy Template'!L6:L}, 
 VALUE('Wheel Strategy Template'!L6:L)>-1, 'Wheel Strategy Template'!L6:L<>""), 9, 1, 6, 1)
```

Comment: Nope still when I make it so I have only 1 active option it lists none. ( I am doing this by deleting the value in G10 on sheet 1. I then only have 1 valid active option and it says in W22 where I have the query that query completed with empty output. If I change the G10  to open so I have 2 active options it then populates and shows 2 options.

Comment: @PierreDanis answer updated with alternative